# How do I join every nth columns together in csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a file with thousands of lines of data. What I want to do is join every nth column together. For example I want to join every 3rd, 4th, and 5th column together and put it a separate column. Is it possible to do so?

Sample Data:
[image: Sample Data]

Output:
[image: Output]

I don't even know where to start so any help is appreciated. I know a way around with pandas but pandas is giving me issues so is there any other way to approach this?

Comment: You seem to be mixing up Row and Column. Please can you edit your question to remove any ambiguities or contradictions?

Comment: If you want 3rd,4th,5th, isn't that 1,2, ***3,4,5*** ,6,7, ***8,9,10*** ,11,12, ***13,14,15***?

Comment: I meant to write rows in all of them sorry, and I don't want commas in between I want them as a series so they are concatenate.

Comment: @a_44, why are you continuing calling **columns** as rows? Can you paste a textual representation of the data?

Comment: I am new to python so I am not completely sure but columns are called rows and rows are called lines correct? I put the sample data exactly like it is the letters of the columns on top and data below it. If its not called rows in python I will fix it to columns

Comment: Where in the world did you read that a column was a row? Python is like everything else I am aware of,  a row is the horizontal elements and a column is the vertical ones.

Comment: Oh sorry I read that somewhere I will go ahead and change it to columns

Answer (score 1):

There is no [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) tag but in case you're open to that, here is a *proposition* with [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
#pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("infile.txt", sep=",") # <- change the sep here to match yours

S1, S2 = 2, 1 #columns to skip at the beginning and while concatenating
N, M = 3, 5 #first range of columns to concatenate

(
    pd.concat([df.astype(str).iloc[:, i+S1:i+M].agg("".join, axis=1)
               for i in range(0, df.shape[1]-M, N+S2)], axis=1)
        .pipe(lambda df_: df_.set_axis(df_.columns.map(lambda x: f"Join {x+1}"), axis=1))
        .to_csv("outfile.csv", sep=",") # <- change the sep here to match yours
)
```

Output (*intermediate*) :

```
  Join 1 Join 2  Join 3
0    345    789  111213
```